# ReactJS/TypeScript - Property 'files' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement' error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am doing a react app with ts and I have this piece of code that returns an error:

```
  const blobfile = document.getElementById('blobFile');
  if ( blobfile !== null ) {
     const file = blobfile.files[0];
  }
```

The error is:

```
Property 'files' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'
```

I tried this but does not work:

```
const file = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('blobFile')).files[0];
```

The error for this is:

```
JSX element type 'HTMLInputElement' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Type 'HTMLInputElement' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': render, context, setState, forceUpdate, and 3 more.ts(2605)
JSX element 'HTMLInputElement' has no corresponding closing tag.ts(17008)
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a multi parts answer

**Part 1.**

If you are using React you should have no reason to use `getElementById`. You should be using the `onChange` event of the file input

```
const onFileChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    console.log(e.target.files)
}

<input type="file" onChange={onFileChange} />
```

**Part 2**

Your type casting is wrong. The idea to type cast is OK, but not strictly correct and `getElementById` could return null.

```
const fileElement = document.getElementById('blobFile') as HTMLInputElement
if (fileElement) {
    console.log(fileElement.files)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much to you, Leon and Michael!

I am using the Leon solution and my code now is:

```
   onFileChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): any => {
      if ( e.target.files == null ) {
         throw new Error("Error finding e.target.files"); 
      }

      return e.target.files[0];
   }
```

and the button:

```
<input type="file" onChange={this.onFileChange} />
```

For better context (I suppose I had to write it in the original post) I am trying to make functional this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/azure-storage-blob-upload-from-browser

Answer (score 0):

Your cast doesn't work because you're working with tsx, and therefore the cast is ambiguous (typescript can't tell if you're making a cast, or trying to instantiate a component). Instead you should do casts using the `as TypeToCastTo`

Eg:

```
 (document.getElementById('blobFile') as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
```

There is a tslint rule "no-angle-bracket-type-assertion" that might help with this: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-angle-bracket-type-assertion/

In addition, you should take a look at Leon's advice regarding using the change event as this is a better solution than querying the document directly - it is very seldom that you would want to do this.